# What is a synonym for "conscious of reputation"?

Tags: synonyms

I am attempting to describe a group of companies that are conscious of their reputation. Is there a single word that can replace the phrase?

Comment: "Prestigious" may be the closer, but it doesn't mean "being conscious of the reputation", although, they should be, normally!

Comment: Big (companies)?

Comment: You'l need to specify what you really want. What are the implications of this kind of consciuosness?

Answer (score 11):

It's a compound phrase, but **image-conscious**:

> concerned about the way one comes across to other people and the impression one creates
>   - [Collins English Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/image-conscious)

It works for organizations as well as individuals.  Of course, this has the negative connotation of being more interested in appearances than realities.  If you mean the opposite, then you want **conscientious**:

> very careful about doing what you are supposed to do : concerned with doing something correctly
>   - [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conscientious)

Comment: Two excellent suggestions. +1.

Comment: Methinks *image-conscious* works especially well in the asker's particular context, as it alludes to those companies' *corporate image*.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean these companies are unwilling to take risks and they play it safe, then...

I'd call these companies [circumspect](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/circumspect)

> Wary and unwilling to take risks
>
> *the officials were very circumspect in their statements*

or [guarded](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/guarded).

> Cautious and having possible reservations:
>
> *he has given a guarded welcome to the idea*

Answer (score 2):

I think "self-aware" is about the closest you'll come, unless you have a specific contextual elaboration of the phrase. Really, there's no great one-word synonym for this abstract concept.

Answer (score 1):

"Brand-conscious" may be another..!

Answer (score 0):

I would use "mindful" if reputation is mentioned in context. If not, "mindful of their influence" would work.

Answer (score 0):

Because reputation has a lot of synonyms, such as prestige, position, distinction, and reliability, you could think of it as a company that wants respect, so in other words you could call this company *prestigious*.

Answer (score 0):

"Prudent" may apply here in some cases.  Or, though more wordy, "Above reproach" can sometimes apply.

Comment: Hello, Bobbo. Please consider supplementing your answer with relevant definitions of _prudent_ and _above reproach_  and an explanation of why you think they are suitable synonyms for "conscious of reputation" in the context of the poster's question.

Answer (score -1):

A word that describes what you're looking for is *proud*.

Comment: Hello, dancho, and welcome to English Language & Usage. Your answer as it stands lacks justification—because you don't provide a relevant definition of  _proud_ and you don't explain why it fits the context that the questioner describes. Please consider strengthening your answer by citing an appropriate definition of _proud_ and explaining its relevance to the poster's question.